# Collection view pagination error with swift 4 & firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, swift4

I've tried to create a home feed which pulls posts from users who the current user is following. Currently it's half working. It pulls the posts from users your following.

I have 2 errors in the code which I cannot seem to fix:

**Refresh error**

When the user pulls to refresh for some reason it displays as the posts twice, instead I intended it to just show the original first 5 posts instead.

**Pagination error**

I'm not quite sure how I can stop the posts from being loaded after the last post has been display currently it just keeps loading the last 5 posts instead of stopping not loading anymore.

**Fetching following posts:**

```
fileprivate func fetchFollowingUserIds() {
    guard let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else { return }
    Database.database().reference().child("user-following").child(uid).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

        guard let userIdsDictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: Any] else { return }

        userIdsDictionary.forEach({ (key, value) in
            Database.fetchUserWithUID(uid: key, completion: { (user) in
                self.fetchPostsWithUser(user: user)
            })
        })
    })
}
```

**Pagination function:**

```
var startKey: String!
fileprivate func fetchPostsWithUser(user: User) {

    guard let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else { return }

    let ref = Database.database().reference().child("posts").child(user.uid)

    if startKey == nil {

        ref.queryOrderedByKey().queryLimited(toFirst: 5).observe(DataEventType.value) { (snapshot) in

            guard var allObjects = snapshot.children.allObjects as? [DataSnapshot] else { return }

            allObjects.reverse()

            allObjects.forEach({ (snapshot) in

                guard let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: Any] else { return }

                var post = Post(user: user, dictionary: dictionary)

                let postId = snapshot.key
                post.id = snapshot.key

                self.startKey = postId
                print(self.startKey)

                self.posts.append(post)

                self.posts.sort(by: { (post1, post2) -> Bool in
                    return post1.creationDate.compare(post2.creationDate) == .orderedDescending
                })
                self.collectionView?.reloadData()
            })
        }

    } else {

        print("Loading more posts")

        guard let lastD = startKey else { return }

        let queryRef = ref.queryOrdered(byChild: "creation_date")
        let queryEndingRef = queryRef.queryEnding(atValue: lastD)
        let queryLimitedRef = queryEndingRef.queryLimited(toLast: 5)
        queryLimitedRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in

            guard var postArray = snapshot.children.allObjects as? [DataSnapshot] else { return }


            postArray.reverse()
            postArray.removeFirst()

            postArray.forEach({ (snapshot) in

                print(snapshot.key)

                guard let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: Any] else { return }

                var post = Post(user: user, dictionary: dictionary)

                let postId = snapshot.key
                post.id = snapshot.key

                self.posts.append(post)

                self.posts.sort(by: { (post1, post2) -> Bool in
                return post1.creationDate.compare(post2.creationDate) == .orderedDescending
                })
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.collectionView?.reloadData()
                }
            })

        }
    }
}

override func scrollViewDidEndDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, willDecelerate decelerate: Bool) {
    let currentOffset = scrollView.contentOffset.y
    let maxOffset = scrollView.contentSize.height - scrollView.frame.size.height
    if maxOffset - currentOffset <= 40{
        fetchAllPosts()
    }
}
```

**Refresh Function**

```
@objc func handleRefresh() {
    print("Handling refresh..")
    posts.removeAll()
    fetchAllPosts()
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.collectionView?.reloadData()
    }
}

fileprivate func fetchAllPosts() {
    fetchPosts()
    fetchTrustingUserIds()
    self.collectionView?.refreshControl?.endRefreshing()
}
```

Comment: during refreshing posts you need to remove all the previous post and and then reload collection view

Comment: and for pagination, you will need to keep the page index you are fetching updated

Comment: @JarvisTheAvenger for the refresh I am doing this if you view the `@objc func handleRefresh` in the code above. I'm not to sure what you mean by keeping the page index could you please give me an example. I appreciate your help.